# How to stitch template with variables dynamiacally?

Tags: php, arrays, templates

I am trying to let the user define the values to be passed into a string.

How can I dynamically stitch some variables with a template without using eval() or having to statically define all the variables?

I am looking for a small foot print solution. Not to include a whole template engine or library.

```
<?php

// Create a template
  $tpl = " ... {$var['a']} ... "; // User defined content

// State variables
  $var = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
  ];

// Stitch
  echo $tpl;
```

So a way for PHP to do late processing of alias/variable replacing.

I thought maybe http_build_query() could be useful to generate a bunch of aliases to use with strtr(). But it doesn't feel clean or proper to do it that way.

Something like this, with support for recursive arrays would do:

```
<?php
  echo strtr(' ... {a.1} ...', $var);
```

Comment: What do you mean by support for recursive arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your substitution format:

```
<?php

$tpl = "Dear @name@, I would love to come to @location@."; 

$subs =
[
    '@name@'     => 'Julian',
    '@location@' => 'Freetown'
];    

echo strtr($tpl, $subs);
```

Output:

```
Dear Julian, I would love to come to Freetown.
```

Alternatively a wrapper around strtr:

```
function template($template_str, array $vars) {
    foreach($vars as $k => $v)
        $substitutes['@'.$k.'@'] = $v;
    return strtr($template_str, $substitutes);
}

$tpl = "Dear @name@, I would love to come to @location@."; 

$subs = [
    'name'     => 'Julian',
    'location' => 'Freetown'
];

echo template($tpl, $subs);
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer the question. This solution is not taking recursive arrays into consideration.

Comment: @tim, explain in your question how you'd like them to be treated.  That's unclear.